# Adding external library to Pycharm when using Python in ArcGIS

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, tar, geohashing

I've installed arcGIS, which uses Python 2.7.  It's sitting here:

```
c:\python27\arcgis10.7
```

I am using PyCharm, and trying to install python-geohash which unfortunately, I cannot do because the interpreter is set to 2.7.  To solve this, I've downloaded the tar.gz file and extracted it:

```
python-geohash-0.8.5
```

The extracted folder is sitting in my PyCharm projects folder:

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\GeoHash\venv\Lib\site-packages
```

Though, when I navigate here:

```
C:\Users\me\PycharmProjects\GeoHash\venv\Lib\site-packages\python-geohash-0.8.5
```

And run:

```
python setup.py install
```

I get:

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

What is best practice here?  Where do I drop the python-geohash-0.8.5 extracted folder, and where do I run the `python setup.py` command so that I can utilize this library in PyCharm?

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  It's a question regarding where to install a package when using Pycharm with an existing version of Python 2.7 in the ArcGIS environment.

Comment: The question shows how to resolve the error that you get when trying to run setup.

Comment: Except that it appears you are using a virtual environment. You have to activate the environment in order to use python from the command line. Google "python virtual environment" for more details.